# консоль linux и putty

Tags: linux, консоль

Есть много команд в консоли которые периодически нужно выполнять, например sudo tail -f /var/log/fail2ban.log открываю периодически смотрю. 
Бывает так что нужно опять например посмотреть sudo tail -f /var/log/fail2ban.log и начинаешь стрелками вверх - низ листать историю команд, пока не находишь нужную.

Может есть какая нибудь "штука" куда бы я добавил команды и что называется, одним кликом вызывал бы нужные мне? Как панель закладок в браузере.

Comment: Создание alias в linux не подходит под Ваши задачи?

Comment: лучше всего ИМХО настроить inputrc правильно и тогда во всех readline-based интерпретаторах (в том числе в bash) можно будет «листать» комманды по уже написанной командной строке с помощью PgUp/PgDown...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

далее описанное относится к программе *bash*, используеющей библеотеку *readline* для редактирования строки ввода и манипуляций с историей команд:

1. нажимаете <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, начинаете вводить произвольную часть текста какой-нибудь из команд, сохранённых в истории. отобразится самая последняя команда, в которой найдено совпадение. нажимая <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> повторно, находите более ранние команды, в которых найдено то же совпадение.

   обратный поиск (к более «новым» командам) по умолчанию осуществляется сочетанием <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>, но, к сожалению, по умолчанию это сочетание задействовано самим терминалом (устройством *tty*) в качестве команды приостановки вывода `stop` (возобновить вывод — дать терминалу команду `start` — можно сочетанием <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>, см. вывод `$ stty -a`). т.е., для использования <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> надо корректировать установки либо терминала, либо библиотеки *readline*.
2. историю команд можно листать не только «по одной за раз» стрелками вверх/вниз, но и с помощью *readline*-овских команд `history-search-backward` и `history-search-forward`. к сожалению, по умолчанию они не привязаны ни к какому сочетанию клавиш (в некоторых дистрибутивах такую привязку всё-таки делают). чтобы привязать их к клавишам, например, <kbd>pageup</kbd>/<kbd>pagedown</kbd>, добавьте в `~/.inputrc` (пользовательский конфигурационный файл библиотеки *readline*) такие строки (чтобы изменения вступили в силу, надо запустить новый процесс программы *bash*):

   ```
   "\e[5~": history-search-backward
   "\e[6~": history-search-forwar
   ```

   если теперь в командной строке ввести несколько символов начала искомой команды, то, нажимая <kbd>pageup</kbd>/<kbd>pagedown</kbd>, можно «пройтись» по всему списку команд, которые начинаюся с этих символов.

Answer (score 4):

**Ctrl + r** -- реверсивный поиск в истории (более подробно сочетания клавиш в командной строке описаны в документации <sup>[1](http://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/readline.3),[2](http://readline.kablamo.org/emacs.html)</sup> на библиотеку *readline*).

Можно сохранить отдельные команды как *alias*'ы или, для более сложных конструкций, в скриптах. Также стоит научиться пользоваться *screen*.

Резюмируя, почитайте книжку, например, знаменитую Эви Немет *UNIX: Руководство системного администратора*. В этом году, кстати, вышло новое издание.

Answer (score 1):

Что бы не искать введенных команд
Создать файл с вашими функциями к примеру:

```
fail2ban() {
sudo tail -f /var/log/fail2ban.log
}
```

И в файле ~/.bashrc внести строку:

`. /Путь к созданному скрипту/имя скрипта.sh`

После авторизации на сервере достаточно будет просто написать `fail2ban` и произойдет чтение лога.
Имя функции может быть любой удобной для написания.

Дополнительно: функции можно указать и в самом ~/.bashrc